# How to count occurrence in two dimension array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, count

## Code Start

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np

List = [[7,12,17,26,29,31],\
      [4,9,11,17,26,27],\
      [5,6,8,21,31,33],\
      [3,17,21,23,27,28],\
      [4,10,18,19,25,27],\
      [5,8,13,19,27,28],\
      [15,16,21,22,27,33],\
      [11,12,13,14,18,33],\
      [2,8,10,18,20,33],\
      [2,7,10,20,27,29],\
      ]

for i in List:
print(i, List.count(i), (List.count(i)/len(List)))
```

## Code End

## Result

```
[7, 12, 17, 26, 29, 31] 1 0.1
[4, 9, 11, 17, 26, 27] 1 0.1
[5, 6, 8, 21, 31, 33] 1 0.1
[3, 17, 21, 23, 27, 28] 1 0.1
[4, 10, 18, 19, 25, 27] 1 0.1
[5, 8, 13, 19, 27, 28] 1 0.1
[15, 16, 21, 22, 27, 33] 1 0.1
[11, 12, 13, 14, 18, 33] 1 0.1
[2, 8, 10, 18, 20, 33] 1 0.1
[2, 7, 10, 20, 27, 29] 1 0.1
```

## Question

How can I get the result like this? Count occurrence of every element by a single line.

```
2 2 0.2
3 1 0.1
4 2 0.2
5 1 0.1
...
33 4 0.4
```

I tried many different ways but always receive the same result.
As I am a newbe to Python, I hope someone can help me figure this out.
BTW, if there is any book explain openpyxl, list manipulation and computational science clearly, please help to recommend.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Occurrence of what?

Comment: Ha ha, Another homework guy.

Comment: @LunaticXavine, in your code when you say `for i in List`,  `i` is a list itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing right now is counting the occurences of each line (as a list) within the numpy array. Since they all appear only once you get a count of 1.

First we have to get all the numbers that appear in the array:

```
unique = np.unique(List)
```

Then we can loop over the rows and count how often they appear:

```
counts = {u:0 for u in unique}
List = np.asarray(List)
for i in unique:
    for row in List:
        if i in row:
            counts[i]+=1
```

Lastly, if you want to print the results:

```
for k,v in counts.items():
    print(k,v,v/len(List))
```